# Angular 2 Corrent Way to Import Modules

Tags: angular

I am trying to import [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2) module to enable oauth2.

I imported the module like this:

main.ts

```
import { OAuthService } from 'angular2-oauth2/oauth-service';
```

and in the systemjs.config.js:

```
   var map = {
     'app': 'app', // 'dist',
     '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
     'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
      'angular2-oauth2': 'node_modules/angular2-oauth2'
    };
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': {main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-oauth2': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
  };
```

For me this way seems correct. However, now I get errors that the dependencies (sha256, js-base64, buffer, base64-js) are missing.

```
...
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/base64-js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/sha256 404 (Not Found)
```

So I tried to add this dependencies in the same way. Which technically work, but then the dependencies of the dependencies are asked.

So, I am wondering how exactly do I import npm modules including their dependencies. I believe it is not meant, that I list all dependencies in the systemjs.config.js.

THX in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because angular2-oauth2 relies on other modules:

```
├─┬ angular2-oauth2@1.3.8 
│ ├── base64-js@0.0.8 
│ ├─┬ buffer@3.6.0 
│ │ ├── ieee754@1.1.6 
│ │ └── isarray@1.0.0 
│ ├── js-base64@2.1.9 
│ └─┬ sha256@0.2.0 
│   ├── convert-hex@0.1.0 
│   └── convert-string@0.1.0
```

You also need to config them within SystemJS:

```
var map = {
  'app': 'app', // 'dist',
  '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
  'angular2-oauth2': 'node_modules/angular2-oauth2',
  'base64-js': 'node_modules/base64-js/lib/b64.js',
  'sha256': 'node_modules/sha256/lib/sha256.js'
};
```

Comment: Thats what I did. As mention above. However, e.g. sha256 asks then for its dependencies (convert-string, convert-hex). So do I need to config all dependencies within SystemJS?